# How to control light spread in a volume?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, volumetrics

Quick question, is there any possibility to control the Area light somehow? I want to achieve a similar effect as you can see in the following image. Basically I need a higher contrast and would like to get the light more "sharp".

[image]

How to achieve that? Any suggestions?

---

Thank you @JachymMichal! That's close, but not exactly what I meant. Because you are using a spot light, the rays are not as parallel as I'd like having them. Basically I'd like to get a pretty harsh contrast and sharp shadow without the soft transitions. Tried to visualize it here:

[image]

Any other solution?

Answer (score 7):

You'll be better off with a *Spot* or *Sun* lamp.
Sharper shadows can be achieved by decreasing *Volumetrics* density.

**Spot lamp**

- for straight rays decrease the spot shape *Angle value*
- for harder shadows increase power and Blend value

**Sun lamp**

- keeps rays perfectly straight
- for harder shadows increase strength and decrease angle

*Example of a Spot light with a narrow cone (8°).*
[image]

*Example of a sun lamp with perfectly parallel rays.*
[image]